# Salesforce Development with Flutter

Tags: mobile, salesforce, flutter

I know that `Flutter` is new, and mobile `Salesforce` development is somewhat a niche topic, but is there full support for mobile `Salesforce` development using `Flutter`?

Comment: Maybe explain what you want to do. This is a bit too broad

Comment: @RémiRousselet Use the Salesforce SDK with Google Dart language when building a mobile app using Flutter?

Comment: @Robs Is there a salesforce mobile SDK for Dart?

Comment: Either there is an HTTP (REST) API you can use from Dart or you create a plugin https://flutter.io/developing-packages/#plugin that makes the Android/iOS mobile SDK available to Dart. I haven't seen it mentioned to be available from somewhere else (ready-to-use) yet.

Comment: @martin There isn't an official one no. How would someone go about creating one?

Comment: @Robs Looking at the [React mobile sdk](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-ReactNative/tree/master/src), it looks like the interactions with Salesforce are all happening through the salesforce [Rest api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_what_is_rest_api.htm). If you look through those, it should give you a good idea of what is usually implemented, and what functionality salesforce makes available.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this can help, but a cursory google search yielded this: https://github.com/wmathurin/SalesforceMobileSDK-FlutterPlugin/tree/dev

Comment: Thanks, but it current has issues: https://github.com/wmathurin/SalesforceMobileSDK-FlutterPlugin/issues/1